# How to download only bytes needed from stackexchange archive 7z files?

Tags: 7-zip, curl, archiving

I am working on a doomsday version of stackexchange completely offline using the dump files in archive.org, some of the site files are rather large where it wouldn't make too much sense to download the entire file over and over for example stackoverflow is nearly 20GB and growing just for Posts alone. I am not sure if this makes sense for 7z the file format used by stackexchange dumps since bytes could be jumbled up.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this without redownloading the entire file again? Maybe is not possible. (I am on linux if that makes a difference)

I've tried using range, but I was unable to put the 7z archive back together by combining the files with cat, and even if it did work I don't know if I could just request the differential bytes added in the next month.

https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/

Comment: I'm not sure whether to applaud your effort or weep for the time you think this may become useful. At current state of play, if both SE as a whole *and* archive.org are gone, I see little hope for the rest of the technological world. You'll need this stuff on paper, or remember it, Farenheit 451-style.

Comment: Have you consider downloading torrent (and individual files inside) instead of files one by one? Also kiwix archives maybe will be more helpful to you.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah is just a pet project. In my line of work I am offline a lot. Also my neighborhood looses power quite often. There are a few projects alike already.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I had never heard of kiwix, looking into it. Thanks.